# How can I show popovers on a mobile browser layout?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, touch-screen, popup

What is the recommended way to share information pertinent to describing a button on a touch-based mobile browser layout?

For desktop browsers the way to solve this is to use popovers that display a snippet of information to passively guide the user through the interface however I'm not sure how to accomplish that on a mobile browser layout where touch is the main interaction.

Comment: A question regarding tooltip on mobile was already asked hier:  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35738/what-are-the-best-practices-for-tooltips-on-mobile-websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using popovers on touch for the same purpose as desktop (to describe what a button does) is not a good idea on mobile.

However popovers on mobile can be used,

1. On the initial tour around the application / introducing a new feature on the app
2. To display action buttons / navigation buttons
3. To display error messages
4. On "What's this" buttons
5. As on focus tool tips (ie: when a text box is selected a tooltip will appear with instructions)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on context. But, in general, if you need a tooltip to explain something, I'd argue that shouldn't be in a tooltip to begin with and should just be a part of the content on the screen by default.

Comment: I agree, but I'm still unsure how I would guide a new user through various elements of the interface otherwise. Should I have a separate "tour" page like stackexchange sites do?

Comment: That's certainly an option.