# Any studies on how styling standard UI elements affect the experience?

Tags: usability, forms, gui-design

I´m interested in understanding how a customized form affect usability and the learning curve on operating an interface.

Sure, we have some guesses that users are used to standard UI,and native elements might have a better performance, but is there any book or article with experimental evidence to support any of the beliefs -- either if **customization improves or worsens the UX?**

Comment: What do you mean by `customization`?  Do you mean custom styling?

Comment: Wbat sort of styling? Color? Size? going from flat to skeumorphic?

Comment: It is related to http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/73518/is-it-true-that-people-expect-tooltips-in-old-looking-systems-but-not-in-new

Comment: By customization I mean defining visual atributes of form elements i.e. color, stroke, size other than the default.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to read this paper :
[An Estimate of a User Learning Curve on Web-Based interface Using Eye Tracking Equipment](https://books.google.com/books?id=6Ei6BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=what%20affects%20the%20learning%20curve%20of%20an%20user%20operating%20an%20interface&source=bl&ots=7M2HamlAvK&sig=4zc2nHLdzDo8DvcZzpMMuwAM5fE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yN8VVbagNMzZsATu-oHIDA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=what%20affects%20the%20learning%20curve%20of%20an%20user%20operating%20an%20interface&f=false)

I am unsure if there is any specific research to check if custom Form elements need a higher learning curve. But It is obvious that a user will take time to adapt to any new elements. In simple words the best interface is one which the user does not even notice. The above paper estimates the learning curve of user operations when using Web-based Interface. It proposes a framework that aims to induce the estimated formula for learning curve by various usability tests.

Hope this helps.