# Should I hide action buttons or let the user press them and then show a message

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, feedback, touch-screen

I have this user interface where the user can batch edit/add/delete Test Types and their weights related to a subject/schooclass combination.

Each test type belongs to a test.

There are actions on buttons which should not always be possible to execute due to business logic coming from the backend like:

- Editing a test type and changing the weight should not be possible if the the  related test(s) has already pupils with scores/grades assigned.
- Deleting a test type should not be possible when this test type has already been assigned to an existing test

As the user can not do anything within that test types view to change the button states I would not disable the edit/delete buttons, but I would hide them.

**Question**
Where is the advantage for the user to **hide those buttons** or let the user click those buttons but get an **error notification** in return like:

- "You are not allowed to change the weight of a test(s) when the pupils already took the test!"
- "You can not delete this test type because it is already assigned to one or many other tests which can not be deleted either else you might loose the pupils grade/scores!"

[image]

UPDATE

I am following the option now to disable the buttons. As I support desktop/mobile clients a tooltip will not work.

Therefore I have this mockup prepared as solution. I hope you like it if not please let me know :-)

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you probably don't want to use exclamation points on your error messages. Users don't like to be yelled at.

Comment: Its just a sample quickly written down in real time here but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As the user can not do anything within that test types view to change the button states I would not disable the edit/delete buttons, but I would hide them."

I disagree with the premise that if the user isn't able to make changes that would make the button active then it should be hidden.

---

Option 1:

If you are presenting the tests all together as in your image, I would **show the button disabled and not clickable**. When the user hovers over the disabled button **a tooltip should tell him why it is disabled**.

---

Option 2:

Avoid the need to present those 4 types (if I understood correctly) of test types in the same list. Instead **present 4 different lists** where each item has the permitted/appropriate actions:

- Editable & deletable test types
- Editable not deletable test types
- Not editable but deletable test types
- Not editable nor deletable test types

The names I used are just so we understand the capabilities of each list of test types.

Comment: Nice... option1 was also yesterday in my mind. I think you misunderstood something: 1.) These are not the tests, the list shows the "Test Types" 2.) the Test Types in the list are not 4. The number of the Test Types can be of any length depending on the teachers need. Please update accordingly :-)  I have added the "touch-screen" tag to this question now as I develop for desktop and mobile. Thus option1 with the tooltip is nice idea but no option.

Comment: About the tooltip on touch devices I'm not 100% sure without seeing the exact case. [This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35738/what-are-the-best-practices-for-tooltips-on-mobile-websites) has some thoughts about it. Maybe instead of tooltips it could be written directly next to the test type.

Comment: @Elisa I think I understood correctly, but let me know if Im still missing the point. There can be any number of categories (let me call them like this instead of test types) and any number of tests belonging to only one category (but a category can have multiple tests). When I mean 4 types I don't mean 4 categories but 4 types of categories, so lets say you can divide these categories in: **•categories which have at least a test associated** (these don't have delete action), **•categories which tests already have pupils** (these don't have the edit action), **etc**.

Comment: oh yu are changing my domain language ;-) I am not sure whether I understand YOU now!  #1 Test has 1 TestType # 1 TestType belongs to N Test # Ok got it now. You divide the TestTypes - which must have a weight of 100 all toghether - into 2 categories depending on related data. Well then I prefer option1. I need to display all of that test types in ONE list because they all make up 100% and the user need to be able to see each items weight. I will not use tooltips instead I will use validation errors on the right side. Just in neutral color as hint. I will update my question with an image :-)

Comment: ok uploaded the image. Let me know what you think!

Comment: I also just discovered the bootstrap popovers which could be used by appending a bootstrap addon to each button and on addon_click the popover with the message is shown. That will be a good tooltip replacement Or I use a tooltip with that button addon:  https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#multiple-addons I could put a "?" char into that addon to let the user know here is something!

Answer (score 4):

Considering usability, it is better practice to have all controls in your page always visible. Otherwise controls look missing or confuse the user looking for follow-up actions which are not in display.

However, changing states (like temporarily disabling submit buttons) can help to prevent false form input. I have added 2 examples.

1. Easy to scan forms allow a conditional submit.
2. More complex forms will rise data validation warnings after submitting. This way the form will have less visual clutter on first view.

[image]

Comment: Hey Rien, for me it looks like you have answered to a total different post/question. Can you directly answer to my question instead of posting some images which are valid in general but have nothing in common with my images? :-)

Comment: Hello Elisa, I will take a more in-depth look for your specific question.

Comment: This is a good answer to your question. If you know they can't do it, don't let them try and do it! IF you hide them, your screen looks like it has no interaction on it. If you let them click an unusable button you make them feel stupid.

Comment: If you can go to the tests and change the test type associated, then either of those conditions could be set back to false and the buttons would be active again. Therefore it doesn't make sense to hide the buttons because they could become enabled again. I would disabled them as this suggestion says and maybe show why they are disabled.

Comment: @JDelossantos I infer from your statement, that you think you can enable/disable those button in the "Test Types View". No you can NOT! There is nothing you can do in the Test Types View to change the State of the Edit/Delete buttons.

Comment: @cheersphilip I do not understand:"...and do it!" Do what? Please also check my comment to JDelossantos which might be interesting for you!

Comment: @Elisa even if I can't change them here (which I've heard you say multiple times), it seems pretty likely that I can change the test types on my individual tests (wherever they are in this interface). Hiding a button implies there is never a way to change it, from this screen or otherwise.

Comment: @JDelossantos Why should hiding the Delete button mean I can not do anything on any other View  thatthis  button Shows again? Thats not logical! Can you please explain more?

Comment: @Elisa - people here are telling you that disabling the buttons is a good idea... you are saying to hide them... how about asking some of your users? This should help you find out what they will find confusing/misleading. If you are really against disabling, then I would strongly recommend avoiding the use of error messages for avoidable mistakes, so hide the buttons. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @cheersphilip There are no users. They are telling disable the buttons without refering to the context. I distinguish 2 buttons edit/delete. All the answers so far just answer a part of my question. Firstly I was for disabling. Then I read so SE thread about hiding buttons when the state can`t be changed in the screen (That thread had an accepted solution) But then I asked here and see again different opinions ;-) That argument "go and ask your users..." does not count else SE would be useless!

Comment: @JDelossantos "_If you know they can't do it..._" I'd say the key is whether _they_ (the users) know they can't do it... If it's very obvious to a user why an action can't be performed (e.g. "Login" button disabled until user/pass entered), then it's OK to disable the button. However, if it's not immediately obvious (as in the OP's case, where being able to edit depends on whether or not scores have been assigned), then it may be better to show a message when clicked.  If you can show tooltips on disabled buttons, then that might also work.

Comment: @TripeHound You are the first to really distinguish here and you try to really understand , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It would suck to be constantly told-off for pressing a button for a test that can't be edited. Makes the user feel stupid.

I'd prefer the buttons that can't be changed to be in a disabled state rather than removed entirely. You could still give the warning message if the user clicks the button as it wouldn't take much for the user to learn that clicking the disabled looking button will give them an error.

If that's not possible, and if the error message is critical to the users' understanding of using the page, then maybe display a cover-all statement paragraph on the page explaining that changes can't be made to tests already in use and hide the buttons. This would be preferable to being nagged at for making wrong decisions.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience and your user case. I think that

- If the function is temporarily available to the user, display the
  action button as disabled status. When the mouse hovers on the action
  button, tell the user the reason the button is disabled and how to
  enable this action.
- If the function is no longer or not allowed to the user, do not
  display the action button to the user, it's useless and totally
  unhelpful.